# Google Pagespeed Jquery increases the total blocking time

Tags: jquery, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I'm using Shopify store, currently my jquery script tag is at the end of the head tag in theme.liquid. According to my research jquery increases total blocking time and decreases pagespeed performance.

```
<head>
bla bla bla...
<script src="{{ 'jquery-3.6.0.min.js' | asset_url }}"></script>
</head>
```

Google pagespeed link: [t.ly/4djC](https://t.ly/4djC)

Comment: add `defer` attribute to all of your scripts and check the site still works correctly. This moves the execution of the scripts until after everything else and stops them blocking the main thread.

Comment: Hi @GrahamRitchie I tried what you said, but the script didn't work in this case :(

Comment: You have to apply it to all scripts, as otherwise jQuery will load too late etc. Also if you have any inline scripts they need moving to the bottom of the page, below your external scripts (because now they only load after everything else).

Comment: Hi @GrahamRitchie I rearranged all the codes as you said, but it doesn't work when I add defer to jquery, unfortunately.

my code layout is like this: https://jsfiddle.net/hy12gckt/5/

Comment: Ah, sorry I wasn't clear, you can't use `defer` on inline scripts, only on external ones. So you need to move any scripts that rely on jQuery to the end and **not** use defer on jQuery (sorry for the bad guidance, now I see the issue). Think of it like this, you tell the browser "don't execute jQuery until after all the HTML has loaded", but then have an inline script that says "hey, use jQuery to do xxx", that inline script obviously fails at that point. It may be tricky on Shopify, but the best way would be to put all inline scripts in a external file and defer that (place it after jQuery)

Comment: See if this helps clear up `defer`, `async` etc. as it has a couple of examples that you can copy paste into a fiddle to understand what it is doing. https://javascript.info/script-async-defer

Comment: Hi @GrahamRitchie No problem, thank you for your help. Yesterday I watched 3 videos about defer and async and read 4 blogs. All I see is jquery cannot be used with defer or async. I guess I need to solve this another way. I also tried. I also tried google external cdn with defer but it did not work as well. :(